# Interior plastics peeling repair

Tags: interior

Some plastic pieces of my car are a bit peeled off and the black plastic behind is shown. Do you know any successful technique to repair them?

The original paint is a matte finish.

You can see pictures here:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have seen some pretty nice 3M foil but it's not available in that particular color...

Answer (score 4):

This repair requires all the skills of a vehicle exterior painter.

We have had limited success with the DIY repair kits that are available for interior plastic repair. They are OK for repairs to older used cars that we prep for sale. However the texture and color match is off better than 75% of the time.  When it has to look original we hire a local mobile service that does an excellent job. Ask for a referral at a local body repair business or a car dealer that sells expensive makes. It takes an artist with skill and practice to do this well. Excellent color match and airbrush skills are needed, mine are just OK.

The process involves a flexible filler for holes and low spots that is then textured with non-stick texture patches to match the surrounding area. Then the area is painted with a flexible paint compatible with plastics and vinyl. This usually involves painting the whole panel because of wear and existing color variations. Clean the area with a plastic paint prep product. Test the paint on the back of a panel to ensure that the paint used will stick and flow on the particular plastic involved. The painting is best done with an airbrush as it atomizes the paint better for a smooth orange peel free surface that does not interfere with the existing texture. It also allows fine edge control in areas where the whole panel is not being painted. No clearcoat is used in this process. Which is why it wears off faster than exterior finishes. It's usually much less than new panels.

Comment: Could you flesh out the procedure a bit more to make it more useful to a DIY-er? Thanks

Comment: @ziad  I filled in some details, HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing off the shelf. It requires the plastic part to be fixed with plastic filler. Then its a matter of having the paint matched at an auto paint shop. This seems like a simple repair but it gets complicated really quick. Mostly because getting the plastics back into original shape requires a good hand.

Your best bet is to go to the junkyard/recycling center and buy some used replacements in good condition. Cheaper and quicker. Don't forget the clips that hold them.